# Compare two different array elements remove the match elements in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have two array objects as below:

```
var arrayOne = [{"Name":"job","SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460"},{"Name":"TestJobSQL","SubscriptionGUID":"09e7dbff7779"}];
var arrayTwo = [{"UserSubscriptionID":13,"SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460","Name":"job"}];
var arrayDiff = [];
```

I need to compare the element **Name** and remove matched element only show not matching array element in **arrayDiff**

as per above example My new  **arrayDiff**  should be

```
var arrayDiff = [{"Name":"TestJobSQL"}]; or var arrayDiff = ['TestJobSQL'];
```

if the **arrayTwo** is

```
var arrayTwo = [];
```

then **arrayDiff** should return

```
var arrayDiff = [{"Name":"TestJobSQL"},{"Name":"Job"}]; or  var arrayDiff = ['TestJobSQL', 'Job'];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var arrayOne = [{"Name":"job","SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460"},{"Name":"TestJobSQL","SubscriptionGUID":"09e7dbff7779"}];
var arrayTwo = [{"UserSubscriptionID":13,"SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460","Name":"job"}];
var arrayDiff = [];
arrayOne.forEach(function(item, index){
    var found = false;
    arrayTwo.forEach(function(item1, index1){
        if(item.Name == item1.Name) {
            found = true;
        }   
    })
    if(found == false) {
        arrayDiff.push({ Name : item.Name});
    }
})
console.log(arrayDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be using lodash's and [`_.differenceBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#differenceBy) method.

It let's you make two arrays diff based on the property you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var createDiffArray = function(attrName,arrayOne,arrayTwo){
   var arrayDif = [];
   for (let element of arrayOne){
      if (arrayTwo.find( x => x[attrName] === element[attrName]) !== undefined){
          arrayDif.push(element[attrName]);
      }  
   }
   return arrayDif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrayOne = [{"Name":"job","SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460"},{"Name":"TestJobSQL","SubscriptionGUID":"09e7dbff7779"}];
var arrayTwo = [{"UserSubscriptionID":13,"SubscriptionGUID":"8ead7edfa460","Name":"job"}];
//arrayTwo=[];
var result = [];


arrayOne.forEach(function(e){
  if(arrayTwo.length==0){
    result.push(e.Name);
  }else{
  arrayTwo.forEach(function(e2){
    if(e.Name!=e2.Name){
      result.push(e.Name);
    }
  })
  }

})
console.log(result);
```